# I'm getting a potential error message concerning MySQL in PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting the following potential error message concerning MySQL in PHPmyAdmin:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.7 this may cause unpredictable behavior.

So far the site that uses this MySQL database seems to run fine, should I be worried in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

No, actually nothing SUPER critic won't happen. Your php mysql library (PHP mysql module) version is 5.0.51a, mysql server version is 5.5.7. phpmydamin just warns you about their non-equalty and that there could be some problems.

Comment: Rightm, so what type of problems are we talking about?

Comment: some `unpredictable behavior` ) . From 5.0.51a to 5.5.7 mysql server developers have added, removed, changed etc. lot of things in their DB. If your modules vesion is 5.0.51a it only knows about mysql-server 5.0.51a (version of mysql-server when module was deployed). Those changes commonly are not critical, but you can encounter some `unpredictable behavior` of phpmyadmin while using it with younger version of php-mysql module.